# HTML Form - AJAX Updates Not Included in Form Submission POST values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple HTML Form that allows users to select a Type value. Based on the selected Type value they can then select from a list of Categories. The Categories are conditional based on the Type - when you select the Type a query is run against a database to select the matching Categories and display these as the select menu.

This is all working well as far as displaying the matching Categories, however when I submit the form the value for the selected Category is not part of the HTTP request and therefore nothing is being added to the database.

Here's the Type field in the HTML Form:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title" class="control-label col-sm-3">Type</label>
  <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type" onchange="getCategories(this.value)">
      <option value="Business">Business</option>
      <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
      <option value="Commercial Land">Commercial Land</option>
      <option value="Land">Land</option>
      <option value="Rental">Rental</option>
      <option value="Residential" selected>Residential</option>
      <option value="Rural">Rural</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

and here's the Categories field in the HTML Form:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="category" class="control-label col-sm-3">Category</label>
  <div class="input-group col-xs-8" class="" id="categoryList">
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you make a selection from the Type menu the following script runs:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function getCategories(str) {
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("categoryList").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("categoryList").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
      var status = xmlhttp.status == 200 ? 'success' : 'error'
      var group = document.getElementById("category")
      group.classList.add(status)
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "getPropertyCategoriesNew.php?type=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  } < /script>
```

which returns the following HTML:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AcreageSemi-rural">AcreageSemi-rural</option>
  <option value="Alpine">Alpine</option>
  <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
  <option value="BlockOfUnits">BlockOfUnits</option>
  <option value="DuplexSemi-detached">DuplexSemi-detached</option>
  <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
  <option value="House">House</option>
  <option value="Land">Land</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  <option value="Retirement">Retirement</option>
  <option value="ServicedApartment">ServicedApartment</option>
  <option value="Studio">Studio</option>
  <option value="Terrace">Terrace</option>
  <option value="Townhouse">Townhouse</option>
  <option value="Unit">Unit</option>
  <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
  <option value="Warehouse">Warehouse</option>
</select>
```

This works in that the Category select menu is populated correctly but when I examine the POST parameters there is no Category parameter. Both of these fields are part of the  and I have a save/submit button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save</button>
```

The form is then processed and I'm checking for the Category value like this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['category']) and $_REQUEST['category'] !=='') { 
$request->setField('category', $_REQUEST['category']);
}
```

Comment: how are you adding to the db,show us your code,does the select with ajax content resides in a form element?

Comment: I see no where in your code where you post the form fields.

Comment: use hidden fields in form and populate them using jquery

Comment: I've updated the question to include details about how the form is processed on submission. I'm simply checking for a $_REQUEST['category'] value which is empty at the moment even though I have selected a Category